# ASP.NET Core - Exception handling not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm trying to create a exception handling middleware, but it's not working the way i need. I need to get the exception that can be throw from any point of the system, then the middleware will get the exception and then will return the exception message and a http code to client as response. When i am debugging, the breakpoint hits the middleware, and i can see the exception message, but the message and the code is not being returned to the client.

This is the code:

```
public class ErrorDto
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseCors("Dev");
    else
        app.UseHsts();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {
            errorApp.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

                if (error != null)
                {
                    var ex = error.Error;

                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDto()
                    {
                        StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                        Message = ex.Message
                    }.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
                }
            });
        });


    app.UseMvc(opts =>
    {
        opts.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide info what actually is returned to the client?

Comment: It is returning a blank result to the client

Comment: What are you using to test? (a separate application, Postman, or a browser?)

Comment: I'm using the browser

Comment: Which browser? (It might not be displaying the body of the error)

Comment: I tested with chrome only

Comment: Can you include the response headers in your question? I tried to reproduce this issue but it all works as expected for me.